# Google Places API missing ID and Referance in response

Tags: json, geolocation, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places API with the following search string

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyDryrzCJoKA-XeN-f3Q2KDPdJHd27Nl7CoM&sensor=true&input=bri
```

The result back look like this:

```
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Bristol, United Kingdom",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 3,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Bristol"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 9,
               "value" : "United Kingdom"
            }
         ]
      }
   ... etc etc
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I can't see an **'id' or 'reference'** property on any of the returned predictions results which is needed in order to then request the full details from the Google Places Details API.

Their documentation says I should see both these items.   https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

Any one know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong method.  You have to use autocomplete:  https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

You're using the "queryautocomplete" service.
Query Autocomplete not returns the place id field.
Try use autocomplete service with this url:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyDryrzCJoKA-XeN-f3Q2KDPdJHd27Nl7CoM&sensor=true&input=bri